# Next js cache revalidation

Tags: next.js, caching

New to Next.js. Using latest version 14.0.X.

I have a route where I fetch data from db base on query id

- product/details?id=1
- product/details?id=2
- product/details?id=3

Data for id=1 could be changed by user (product description for example, or price).

When user change it, I revalidating this path 'product/details'.

I'm suspect in this case cache data for id=2 and id=3 is also will be revalidating even it's hasn't been changed?

If that the case what is a correct way to revalidate only what i need?

1. Should I revalidate exact path, like this
   revalidatePath('product/details?id=3')
2. Or it make sense instead passing id as query, create a dynamic folder
   /product/details/**id**?q1=v1

and when data changed by user, just revalidate '/product/details/**id**'?

What is a best practice/right way to do it here?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: For creating dynamic routes with Dynamic Segment, You can try to follow the convention in the docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes

- If you're using app router:

  ```
  File name: app/product/details/[id]/page.js
  Example URL: /product/details/1
  ```
- Or, If you're using pages router:

  ```
  File name: pages/product/details/[id].js
  Example URL: /product/details/1
  ```

Step 2: You can choose a revalidate mechanism of your choice. Example: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidatePath

- Revalidating A Specific URL

  ```
  import { revalidatePath } from 'next/cache'
  revalidatePath('/blog/post-1')
  ```

  This will revalidate one specific URL on the next page visit.
- Or, Revalidating A Page Path

  ```
  import { revalidatePath } from 'next/cache'
  revalidatePath('/blog/[slug]', 'page')
  ```

  This will revalidate any URL that matches the provided page file on the next page visit. This will not invalidate pages beneath the specific page. For example, /blog/[slug] won't invalidate /blog/[slug]/[author].

Comment: Well thanks for replay, but this is not what I'm asking. 
Your example  and documentation showing how to  revalidate a path. In my case pass is always the same, only query string changes. 

I looking something like 
revalidatePath(path, {
query: someQuery})

Or revalidate by tag maybe.

Comment: Okay, 
This could be done using tag.

When you fetch productById I adding a tag 

 const res: Response = await fetch(`${appConfig.BASE_URL}/product?id=${id}`, {
    cache: 'default',
    next: { tags: [id] }, // Add tags here
  })


And then in server action where you updating this product, run 

revalidateTag(id) // same id 

If you revisiting a page, it will be updated with lates data.